# How to delete all element of an array in a list of arrays

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a list of arrays look like this:

```
var lists = [[Category]]()
```

Each element in the "lists" represents an array of object (Category), I'm trying to reinit the "lists" (clear every element) after using it.

My approach:

```
lists.forEach { list in 
    list.removeAll()
}
```

Error: Can not mutate the "list" because "list" is a constant variable

Is there anyway I can achieve my goal in Swift?

Comment: Why not just do `lists = [[Category]]()`? (resets to default again)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying my problem, my goal is to clear all the array that stored in "lists" not reinit the "lists". I have a function call clearList([[Category]]), I want to removeAll element of array that I pass in the function. Look like this: clearList([listCate1, listCate2, ...]) if I want to delete more list, I just have to pass through the array paramater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays are value types and they have copy-on-write semantics, "clearing all the nested arrays of an array" is indistinguishable from "creating a new array with as many empty nested arrays as there are nested arrays in the old array, and reassigning it to the old array".

So you can do

```
lists = Array(repeating: [], count: lists.count)
```

Alternatively:

```
lists = lists.map { _ in [] }
```

From the comments, it seems like you are writing a function that clears all the nested arrays. In that case, you need an `inout` parameter:

```
func clearList(_ lists: inout [[Category]]) {
    lists = Array(repeating: [], count: lists.count)
}
```

And to call it:

```
var myLists = [listCate1, listCate2]
clearList(&myLists)
// myLists will be [[], []], note that this does not change listCate1 or listCate2
```

If you *really* want your function to mutate an arbitrary number of lists that you pass in, you'd need to use unsafe pointers (very not recommended):

```
func clearList(_ lists: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Category]>...) {
    for list in lists {
        list.pointee = []
    }
}
```

And `clearList(&listCate1, &listCate2)` would actually change `listCate1` and `listCate2`, but this is a rather dirty trick.

Comment: I think it my mistake when I don't clarify my problem, I have a function called "clearList" the goal is to clear every list I pass in, so the "lists" I mention above is just a container. What I want here is to removeAll element of list I pass in the function, so I use a "lists" to store all those lists. It look something like this clearList([listCate1, listCate2, ...]) if I want to delete more list i just have to pass in through the array parameter.

Comment: @BacSon I have tried to achieve what you want. See the edit. You seem to have a misunderstanding of Swift's value type. Whenever you assign them to something, pass them to a function, or when you change something about them, you are creating a copy of the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it's my mistake when I don't clarify what my problem is. Actually I want to change listCate1 and listCate2, remove all their elements but if it is a dirty trick, I would rather not use. Just change it to the normal way
clearList() { listCate1.removeAll(), listCate2.removeAll() }
I just wonder is there any smarter solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an empty array literal which is written as [ ] (an empty pair of square brackets)

```
lists = []
```

lists is now an empty array, but still of type `[[Category]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the element of an array and keep the capacity.

```
lists.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
```

or if you want to remove object from array based on some conditions then you can use this...

```
lists.removeAll { (obj) -> Bool in

   if <check some condition {   return true  }
   else { false  }
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var someInts1 = [30,11,34]
    var someInts2 = [30,11,34]
    var someInts3 = [30,11,34]

    var lists = [Any]()
    lists = [someInts1, someInts2, someInts3]
    print(lists) // [[30,11,34], [30,11,34], [30,11,34]]

    lists = [] // this is where the list become empty
    print(lists) // []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an extension with mutable and immutable variants. By extending `RangeReplaceableCollection` rather than `Array` we don't need to constrain `Array.Element` to any specific type.

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func stripped() -> Self {
        return .init(repeating: .init(), count: count)
    }

    mutating func strip() {
        self = stripped()
    }
}
```

Now we can strip in place if our array is declared mutable:

```
var mutable: [[Category]] = []
mutable.strip()
```

Or we can use the immutable variant for `let` constants:

```
let immutable: [[Category]] = []
let stripped = immutable.stripped()
```